# SQL/VBA: How to group by a fiscal year starting from a day other than 1st day of month

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I’m trying (using MS Access) to group some data by a fiscal year, which can be different to the calendar year.

If every fiscal year always started on the 1st of a given month, then the solution would be simple: one could simply use an if statement like this:

```
FY: IIf(Month([orderdate])<month([startFYofaCompany]);Year([orderdate])-1;Year([orderdate]))
```

in a select query like

```
SELECT statement here AS FY, Sum(something) AS SumOfSth
GROUP BY statement here;
```

However, the difficulty in my case is that a financial year of a given company can start from date other than 1st of a given month. I’ve looked for a solution, but everyone assumes otherwise.

I’d be grateful if someone had the same problem and could share a solution.

Edit:
There is no pattern re. fiscal year – the database consists of multiple companies and should work whether some company has a FY starting on 2nd, 3rd, 15th, or any other day of any given month. The start date is stored in a separate field (in the pseudo-code above: startFYofaCompany).

Comment: Instead of explaining how a financial (fiscal) year might not start on the 1st of a month, **define exactly when it will start**.  Is there a pattern to when the fiscal year starts?  A pattern to the financial quarters?  If the pattern is rather basic, it could perhaps be easily programmed.  For a more complicated pattern, it might be worth building a table of dates which define the fiscal year and quarters (or other periods).  Such a table could prove very useful and efficient for joining with other tables, perhaps more so than messing with date formulas and functions.

Comment: Thanks for response. There’s no pattern: the FY can start on 2nd as well as on 25th. I have a separate table with field for a start of FY and another field for end of FY, so the FY is defined differently for each company. I guess I can build a separate table for years and quarters for every company, but there is no time limit for the data to be grouped, it easily can be 100+ years forward. Also, there can be many companies, so this solution would require building a 100+ years table for each, which can turn out to be not enough when a user enters some data for a date not included in such table.

Comment: But if each company really has different dates with no particular pattern, then somewhere such dates must be stored.  If there is truly no way to calculate future dates, then you just need to accept such dates as something that needs to be entered like many other points of data for each company each year.  Concern about such sizes are not needed.  A table of millions of records is still very efficient, so 100+ years for multiple companies is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have month + day to take into consideration, then obviously you will need the corresponding 2 fields in your table (`NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`).

Once this is added, the following will calculate the year:

`year(orderDate) - IIF(dateserial(year(orderDate), startFYofaCompany_month, startFYofaCompany_day) > orderDate, 1, 0)`

Add this to the 2 places you have prepared in your query.

Comment: Neat, exactly what I was looking for. Can I skip adding additional fields and simply modify the statement like: `Year([orderdate])-IIf(DateSerial(Year([orderdate]);Month([startFYofaCompany]);Day([startFYofaCompany]))>[orderdate];1;0)`?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly valid. Note: just like I would need to add some constraints to make sure I input only correct data (e.g. **NOT** 35 of April), you will need to add some for your code to never fail, that is, do something about **29th of February** when not on a leap year (either prevent the start date to be set to it or convert 29 to 28 when needed in the formula above. For instance, you may force the year of `StartFYofaCompany` to be 2001. After that, it is up to you to decide which version is more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple, and you don't need any additional table or fields.

The method is to offset the financial dates to match the calendar year. For example:

```
FinancialYearFirstMonth = 9
FinancialYearFirstDay = 2
```

First, toalign to primo of the month:

```
DateMonth = DateAdd("d", 1 - FinancialYearFirstDay, SomeDate)
```

Next, expand to also align to primo of the year:

```
DateYearMonth = DateAdd("m", 1 - FinancialYearFirstMonth, DateAdd("d", 1 - FinancialYearFirstDay, SomeDate))
```

If the financial year is not lagging but leading the calendar year, add 12 months:

```
DateYearMonth = DateAdd("m", 1 - FinancialYearFirstMonth + 12, DateAdd("d", 1 - FinancialYearFirstDay, SomeDate))
```

Now you can have the *financial* *year* and *month* and (with some limitations for the ultimo date(s) of a month) *day* using the normal functions:

```
FinancialYear = Year(DateYearMonth)
FinancialMonth = Month(DateYearMonth)
FinancialDay = Day(DateYearMonth)
```

Of course, month *names* will not fit. If these are needed, use *MonthName* of the original date.